How to change custom nested configuration App.Config from code?
I used solution from this topic How to have custom nested configuration App.Config nodes and section. But I need a possibility to change values in custom section's properties from code. Now I have "System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'The configuration is read only.'" error on setter of properties like this
    [ConfigurationProperty("ChartName", IsRequired = true)]
    public string ChartName
    {
        get => (string)this[nameof(ChartName)];
        set => this[nameof(ChartName)] = value;
    }


If you want to do some kind of fancy configuration, have you considered storing a json file in your appdata folder? That should give you a fairly simple way to store arbitrary object hierarchies.

Yes. But I am already used standard Settings.settings and looks like for another settings are better to add them is the same place. But if I won't find solution I will use another config file
